# Offline use of react-google-login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-api

I'm using [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) to create a backup of gmail. This will access the gmail API and download new emails each day at a certain time.

I am currently trying to pass the code I receive for offline access to my backend from the frontend (website.com/settings) and post it to /oauth2/v4/token/ as per the oauth2 playground settings. I am posting it using the [googleapis nodejs client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client), but I keep getting a 400 redirect_uri error.

I have tried using both the web client_secret.json (throws redirect_uri error), and a different offline client_secret.json (resulted in a 401 unauthorized)

Here is the backend code that is throwing the error:

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');

const keys = require('./client_secret.json');

const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
  keys.web.client_id,
  keys.web.client_secret,
  keys.web.redirect_uris[0]
);
const code =
  '4/AAANOAO_WLctYCyBJ0FfU_NP5V0c-iT8J_og0WRecywLTKJkmyw5HyXMKVLiIAAgrK84FsseyDxJO7hfjtTHl2c';

async function getToken(code) {
  const r = await oAuth2Client
    .getToken(code)
    .then(res => console.log('success!', res))
    .catch(err => console.log('error', err))
}

getToken(code);
```

Comment: In your google dev API (when setting up the project) did you specify the redirect URIs allowed? Did you include the location which you're posting from? That's a common cause of the redirect_uri error

Comment: Hi Jayce - I have specified localhost:3000/, localhost/, localhost:3000/settings. But on the server side I am just posting the code using getToken() and am trying to just console.log that token. 

Would that mean that I would need to set up an app.get path to receive a response for getToken()? Or is there some way I can direct that just back to the server-side request I make?

I've also tried using offline credentials (including the redirect_uri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" used for other offline credentials and including the redirect_uri as an empty string), but nothing seems to work

Comment: Are your authorized URI's under 'Javascript Origins', 'redirect URIs' or both? You shouldn't need a special path to receive the response, it should just be returned to where the request came from (assuming that address is authorized). Also why does the OAuth2Client only take the first redirect URI in the array as an argument? And have you tried using this project for regular Google authentication (not offline access, just plain old Google authentication).

Comment: Sorry for the delays - was in calculus class. I've got URIs authorized under javascript origins and redirect_uris. Got the same URLs in both aside from the oauth2 playground, which is also in authorized redirect uris. I thought I couldn't use all of them, so I was just picking one redirect_uri (localhost:3000 in this case). When I tried to do it without the index I was also getting a redirect_uri error. 

The code does seem to work. When i don't use the offline access flag it seems to work. That being said, I need offline access to get gmail nightly, right?

Comment: So I've browsed through a couple of repositories and it looks like all examples I've seen make another call on the JS side of things in order to get the auth token set up. Somewhat frustrating I can't just pass the code through to Node and have it all processed there, but we'll see where it leads from there. Examples I looked at https://github.com/bddowningjennings-dev/basic-js-examples/blob/ec484b6031a5991697f6d06ba5aad0dd2f1aca90/google-cal/gapi/src/App.js & https://github.com/cuappdev/clicker/blob/46041959a87045d5edfaa3f8dc04a1ac597493c2/src/components/common/ClickerGoogleSignInButton.js